# How to get all properties in a method of same base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

Actually, I want to access properties of a base class in a method and I am not instantiating that object directly. Below is code, I am working on:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        drivedclass obj = new drivedclass();
        obj.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class drivedclass : baseclass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        LoadSomeThing();
    }
}

public class baseclass
{
    public string property1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string property2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public void LoadSomeThing()
    {
        //here I want to access values of all properties
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way, I can access the properties in method of same class and that class is base class.

Comment: Question is really unclear at the moment

Comment: Just try it and you will have a bunch of info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them with reflection, but this is not the 'normal' way.

```
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    prop.SetValue(this, newValue);
}
```

If you want to make it 'cleaner', you should make the properties virtual.

Comment: Glad you added the note that it's not the normal way :) I have a feeling that OP is just learning the principles of inheritance and that reflection is not really what they're looking for.

Comment: You're suggesting reflection for a class to access it's own `public` properties?

Comment: @Rotem why not?, I only showed it can be done with reflection, but i would be better to implement it without reflection. If he is making something like a serialization that will also write properties of derived-classes. It _can_ be done this way. Otherwise, he should rethink his object model. He should implement virtual/abstract properties.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Read the question again :) You're suggesting reflection for an object to access its **OWN** properties.

Comment: @Rotem good notice :), some people interpret ' _//here I want to access values of all properties_ '  as all properties including the derived class properties. :)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ah I see what you mean. Well if that is what OP wants then, as you said a redesign is in order.

Comment: I was looking for similar solution. I do not want to access the derived class properties.

Comment: If you don't want the properties of derived classes (with reflection) use foreach(PropertyInfo prop in typeof(baseclass).GetProperties())

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `property1` and `property2` as they are.

However, note that in `LoadSomeThing()` you will not be able to access any properties of `drivedlcass`, because base classes cannot see properties of their derived classes by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method to enumerate all property values:

```
        public void EnumerateProperties()
    {
        var propertiesInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertiesInfo)
        {
            var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're suggesting reflection for a class to access it's own `public` properties?

Comment: @Rotem: Is not got to use reflection for accessing public properties?

Comment: It was unclear from your question that you want to enumerate all class properties.

Answer (score 0):

Question is quiet unclear but if you wish to access your properties, they are well present in both the Base class and the derived class. thus, if you do  `s = obj.property2` in your main class Test, that should be available.

```
public class Test {
    public static void Main( ) {
      drivedclass obj = new drivedclass( );
      obj.DoSomething( );
      string s = obj.property2 ;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always make it explicit:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Property3
    { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething ()
    {
        LoadSomeThing();
    }

    public override void LoadSomeThing ()
    {
        base.LoadSomeThing();
        Console.WriteLine(Property3);
    }
}

public class BaseClass {
    public string Property1
    { get; set; }
    public string Property2
    { get; set; }

    public virtual void LoadSomeThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Property1);
        Console.WriteLine(Property2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try: this.property1